# How to plot rows of same columns on top of each other

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

This is what my data looks like:

year, locationkey, sales

[image]

x axis should have a year and color of line plot should show the location while the trend or plot itself should be sales. The catch here is that each location should come on top of each other. How do I do that?
for example: first line should show sales of location 1 on 2016-2019 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to pivot the data so each location is a separate column, then plot the pivoted data.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# just same dummy data
df=pd.DataFrame([['2016','1',123],
                 ['2017','1',134],
                 ['2018','1',154],
                 ['2016','2',234],
                 ['2017','2',240],
                 ['2018','2',259],
                 ['2016','3',304],
                 ['2017','3',324],
                 ['2018','3',384],
                 ['2016','4',414],
                 ['2017','4',424],
                 ['2018','4',444]
                ], columns=['Year','Location','Sales'])

# Create a pivot table from the raw data
pivoted=df.pivot_table( values='Sales', index='Year',
               columns=['Location'], aggfunc="sum")

# Not sure why, but plot doesn't like the index structure of a pivot table
# so I'm flattening it here:
pivoted.reset_index(inplace=True)

# Create the plot
ax=pivoted.plot(xticks=pivoted.index)
plt.gca().set_xticklabels( pivoted.Year )
ax.set_ylabel('Sales');
ax.set_xlabel('Year');
```

[image: sample output]